# Where is the HTML for a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I was looking through Brandon Rhodes' [Pandas CSS file](https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pycon-pandas-tutorial/blob/master/style-table.css), and I'm struggling to find what the HTML looks like for a Pandas DataFrame.

Basically I'm trying to figure out how to freeze the DataFrame's header row so I can view the header even if I scroll down.  But I don't have any insight into what the raw HTML looks like so I can access divs and classes.  How would I find it?

Answer (score 0):

you can look at the HTML code for a given dataframe df by calling

```
df.to_html()
```